# How can I incorporate category and tag descriptions into my WordPress child theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am preparing to launch a new look for my WordPress site. Rather than reinvent the wheel when there are so many GPL themes out there already, I picked one that had most of what I wanted and set about customizing it. However, I've hit a stumbling block.

In the theme I'm customizing, archive titles are controlled by a function in functions.php. I have the following code in my child theme's functions.php (this is derived from an identical code block in the parent theme's functions.php file):

```
function theme_get_meta_title() {
$patt = '<div class="bg-white text-center text-uppercase meta-title"><h2 class="text-gamma">%s</h2></div>';

if(is_archive()) {
    return sprintf($patt, get_the_archive_title());
} else if(is_search()) {
    return sprintf($patt, get_search_query());
}

}

endif;
```

This produces a white box in between my content and navigation bar with a heading (either a category title, tag title, or a date). Not being shown are the descriptions I've previously created for my categories and tags. Having gone to the trouble of creating these descriptions, I'd like them to show up on the frontend when visitors are viewing a category or tag archive. I've tried to modify this function to add in descriptions, but I'm not getting results.

I started by simply trying to add in category descriptions:

```
function theme_get_meta_title() {
$patt = '<div class="bg-white text-center text-uppercase meta-title"><h2 class="text-gamma">%s</h2></div>';

if(is_category()) {
    return sprintf($patt, get_the_category(), category_description());
} else if(is_archive()) {
    return sprintf($patt, get_the_archive_title());
} else if(is_search()) {
    return sprintf($patt, get_search_query());
}

}

endif;
```

However, this did not work, and neither did other permutations I tried. I'd like to be able to display tag as well as category descriptions after the headings (but inside the div that's creating that white box), and on date-based archive displays, simply have a stock message saying, *You are browsing an archive of older posts* after the heading. What is the correct way to go about doing this?

Comment: you are sure this function is used on the template you are using?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive that function is responsible for determining what appears on archive pages for this theme.

Answer (score 1):

Sprintf works by finding arguments to match to. You have only provided one argument in the string so only the first argument is matched. Plus you had a error in your code.

```
 function theme_get_meta_title() {
    $patt = '<div class="bg-white text-center text-uppercase meta-title"><h2 class="text-gamma">%s</h2> <div class="description">%s</div>   </div>';

    if(is_category()) {
        return sprintf($patt, get_the_category(), category_description());
    } else if(is_archive()) {
        return sprintf($patt, get_the_archive_title());
    } else if(is_search()) {
        return sprintf($patt, get_search_query());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This link shows an aproach to what you are trying to do:
[wordpress forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-category-description-1)

Comment: I actually came across that thread while searching. Wasn't all that helpful since the theme I'm customizing doesn't have category or tag templates I can drop `<?php echo category_description(); ?>` into.